# Is this 2d five-fold Venn Diagram original and valid?

Tags: logic

Venn diagrams captured my attention a few years ago. One night I decided to see if I could come up with some new Venn Diagrams. After a few hours, this is what I came up with. I'm a web developer not a mathematician, so I'm quite proud of this little creation. I've searched the internet and several books to confirm that this construction is unique. Lastly, I wanted to post it here because I know that the this crowd has more resources and knowledge than are available to me.

[image: http://i55.tinypic.com/303jksh.jpg]

Comment: I inserted the image into the post. I hope you do not mind.

Comment: Thank you so much! I like that much better :)

Comment: Looks ok, just a small typo: you have AEC written twice (once as "AEC" and once as "ACE") , one of them is actually ACD.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems okay to me.

You might want to take a look at a very nice paper that appeard in the *Notices of the American Mathematical Society* in 2006 about Venn diagrams:

- Ruskey, Frank; Savage, Carla D.; Wagon, Stan.
  **The search for simple symmetric Venn diagrams.**
  *Notices Amer. Math. Soc.* **53** (2006), no. 11, 1304–1312.

At least I (an AMS member) can access it [in PDF format on the web](http://www.ams.org/notices/200611/ea-wagon.pdf). I don't know if the link will work for someone who is not a member, though.

Comment: There's also the survey by Ruskey and Weston at http://www.combinatorics.org/Surveys/ds5/VennEJC.html

Comment: This is excellent! The link works fine. The paper looks wonderfully interesting. I cant thank you enough.