# Generating generalised Venn diagrams

Tags: elementary-set-theory, plane-curves

David McCandless of "Information is Beautiful" recently posted an image of the [7-set Venn diagram construction](http://pinterest.com/pin/122934264799002426/).

What rules generate Venn diagrams for an arbitrary number of sets $k$?

Comment: Did you check the references in the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram)? The first link has a section called [A General Construction for Symmetric Venn Diagrams](http://www.combinatorics.org/files/Surveys/ds5/VennSymmEJC.html#construction).

Comment: Related questions:
[Why can a venn diagram for 4+ sets not be constructed using circles?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/why-can-a-venn-diagram-for-4-sets-not-be-constructed-using-circles) and
[Is this 2d five-fold Venn Diagram original and valid?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7919/is-this-2d-five-fold-venn-diagram-original-and-valid)

Answer (score 3):

Since this is an interesting topic, I thought that it might be useful to collect interesting references on this topic. I made the post CW, feel free to edit it.

First of all the [references given in Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram#References) might be useful.

Maybe some information on the [talk page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3aVenn_diagram) of that article could be useful, too. E.g. the link to review of Cogwheels of Mind given [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3aVenn_diagram#Edwards_and_other_post-Venn_diagrams).

---

Here is an alphabetical list of some more interesting papers related to this topic.

- Branko Grünbaum: *The search for symmetric Venn diagrams*; Geombinatorics 8(1999), pp. 104 - 109
  [author's homepage](http://www.math.washington.edu/~grunbaum/BG228.pdf). Note: The same author has several other papers on the same topic.
- Branko Grünbaum: *The Construction of Venn Diagrams*, The College Mathematics Journal, Vol. 15, No. 3 (Jun., 1984), pp. 238-247; [jstor](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2686332).
- Peter Hamburger, Raymond E. Pippert: *Venn Said It Couldn't Be Done*, Mathematics Magazine, Vol. 73, No. 2 (Apr., 2000), pp. 105-110; [jstor](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2691081)
- Ruskey, Frank; Savage, Carla D.; Wagon, Stan. *The search for simple symmetric Venn diagrams*. Notices Amer. Math. Soc. 53 (2006), no. 11, 1304–1312.
  [link](http://www.ams.org/notices/200611/ea-wagon.pdf)
- Allen J. Schwenk: *Venn Diagram for Five Sets*, Mathematics Magazine, Vol. 57, No. 5 (Nov., 1984), p. 297; 
  [jstor](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2689606)

Answer (score 2):

Using ellipses, you can construct a symmetrical Venn diagram for all orders $k$:
http://www.ams.org/notices/200611/fea-wagon.pdf